# Combine Web API 2 and Service Stack in one app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack

I am developing an application with Angular 1.5 and Web API 2, but I would like to switch to ServiceStack. The app is running already in production.

The idea is to have v1 with Web API (.../api/v1/...), implement v2 with ServiceStack and after some time drop v1.

I wonder if it is possible to combine Web API 2 and ServiceStack in one web host? If no, what is the best way to proceed with a smooth transition without spending time on rewriting the whole code with ServiceStack in one step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [MVC Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration#enabling-servicestack-in-webconfig) docs which shows how you can configure ServiceStack so that it can be configured together with alternative web frameworks, e.g. You can register ServiceStack to be mounted at `/api/v2` with:

```
<location path="api/v2">
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" 
           verb="*"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" 
           type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" 
           preCondition="integratedMode" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

You'll also need to specify it in your ServiceStack's `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    HandlerFactoryPath = "api/v2"
});
```